# Как настроить git на сервере Centos?

Tags: bitbucket, git, github

Чтобы скопировать проект с сервера на репозиторий?
Установил git, дальше отредактировал user, email в настройках.
После зашел в папку с проектом на сервере и выполнил команду:

```
get init
get add *
get commit -m 'Init text'
```

Побежал длинный список файлов в консоли. Что дальше? Как загрузить файлы с сервера в репозиторий?

Comment: @Vasile, это не серьезно. Вы ведь не понимаете, что такое git. Ваш вопрос в текущей формулировке звучит мягко говоря "глупо". Есть [же сайты][1], где все подробно расписано и объяснено, уделите пару часов, прочитайте от корки до корки и тогда по существу зададите вопросы, если не поняли какие-то моменты.

  [1]: http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1

Comment: Повторюсь. @Vasile, [вот видео коротких уроков](http://goo.gl/RHQIVO) по git от loftblog. Ознакомьтесь. Сперва необходимо научится пользоваться консолью, чтобы понимать всю внутреннею кухню, которая происходит под капотом отдельно взятой IDE.

И, конечно же, man-ы, которые предложил уважаемый @likerRr :)

Comment: Спасибо, уже кое что успел прочесть - дополнил вопрос

Comment: Спасибо - просмотрел уроки - стало все ясно. Остается вопрос в использовании PHPSTORM, какая последовательность действий, когда добавил новый файл в проект или же отредактировать и хочу закоммитить изменения

Comment: @Vasile, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Создать репозиторий на Github/Bitbucket.
- Добавить удалённый репозиторий `git remote add origin https://github.com/ваше_имя/название_репозитория.git`
- Коммитим изменения: `git commit -m "First commit"`
- Отправляем изменения в репозиторий: `git push origin master`

#### Обновление

Вы уже создали репозиторий через консоль, в папке вашего проекта появилась скрытая директория `.git`. PHPStorm не глуп и это заметил. У Вас стали доступны дополнительные опции в меню `VCS`. Кроме того, вы должны заметить разную расцветку, как в древе файловой структуры Вашего проекта (по умолчанию справа), так и в самом файле (изменения в строках).

Чтобы добавить вновь созданный файл/файлы в репозиторий (после создания он/они красного цвета), выделяем его/их и в контекстном меню выбираем `Git -> Add`, либо hot key `Ctrl + Alt + A`.

Чтобы закоммитить `Ctrl + K`.

Чтобы запушить `Ctrl + Shift + K`.

[Смотрим видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VvZbNOg5Nc).

Comment: Последний вопрос, с сервера я загрузил проект на ведро, далее склонировал проект на локальный компьютер. С компьютера я могу делать коммиты и грузить на ведро изменения. Вопрос, как обновить отдельный файлы(список файлов) на сервере в ведра, то бишь загрузить изменения на продакшн сервер?

Comment: На сервере стоит git

Comment: @Vasile Уф,всё верно, только звено "продакшен сервер" необходимо убрать из Вашей цепочки. Вы (локальная машина/dev-сервер) взаимодействуете только с "ведром". Когда Вы решите,что всё работает,как надо (оттестировано, выверено "логарифмической линейкой" и т.д.),то заходите на свой "боевой" сервер и клонируйте свой репозиторий с "ведра",либо используете менеджером пакетов. Последний нынче у каждого языка имеется. К примеру, у PHP это [composer](https://getcomposer.org/),js - [bower](http://bower.io/),... Вся эта стадия называется deploy.

Comment: Чтобы загрузить все изменения с ведра на сервер, использую команду: `git pull origin master`

А можно ли загрузить отдельные файл или коммиты?

Comment: @Vasile Соединение первого и второго с автоматизацией - это отдельная песня. Уверен, что на данном этапе это для Вас избыточно, т.к. один боевой сервер.

А вот тестирование/покрытие тестами/качество кода автоматизировать можно и нужно. Для этого используют [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/), Coveralls(http://coveralls.io/), [Scrutinizer](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/),... Можно посмотреть, как это сделано у "старшеньких", либо [у меня](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-cache)

Comment: @Vasile Кстати, даже можно подготовить изолированную, настроенную среду для запуска Вашего проекта всеми желающими через [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/). Можете посмотреть, как [это сделано у меня](http://goo.gl/aapoQC) (используется связка Docker + Ansible).

Comment: @Vasile

> git pull origin master

Нет.

    git clone https://github.com/ваше_имя/имя_вашего_репозитория.git

> А можно ли загрузить отдельные файл или коммиты?

Если подобное как-то возможно, то это явно нестандартный сценарий.

Поэтому, только весь проект целиком. Для закачки пофайлово, используют старый добрый [(S)FTP](http://goo.gl/Qi74Vx).